# Is it possible to log from the Java Debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, logging, hook

Stepping through code to debug it may not always be sensible, like in case of concurrency issues. It would seem more useful to me to log all necessary things to a file or database and analyze the data when a problem in fact occurred. Of course this could be done from inside the methods itself, but it would be messy:

```
public int square(int value) {
    return value * value;
}
```

vs.

```
public int square (int value){
    output.begin(this, "square", value);
    try {
       int result = value * value;
       output.end(this, "square", value);
       return result;
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        output.throwz(this, "square", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And it is not possible (in terms of work hours) to do it with an existing large codebase. Is there a way to attach code from inside my program to be executed on method call or return to do something like this?

```
                          /* !! This is pseudo code, not Java !! */

Runtime.getRuntime().setMethodBeginListener(new MethodBeginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMethodBegin(Thread t, Object o, Method m, Object[] args) {
        // log it
    }
});

Runtime.getRuntime().setMethodEndListener(new MethodEndListener() {
    @Override
    public Object onMethodEnd(Thread t, Object o, Method m, Object returnValue) {
        // log it
        return o;
    }
});

Runtime.getRuntime().setMethodThrowsListener(new MethodThrowsListener() {
    @Override
    public Object onMethodThrows(Thread t, Object o, Method m, Throwable t) {
        // log it
        throw t;
    }
});
```

(`Thread` argument would be obsolete if the method would be executed in by the same thread.) I know that this would create additional workload, so be it. I am aware that there are other programming languages like AspectJ which provide better for this, but I am looking for a way in Java (web apps, to be precise) to use the debugger, such that I can add a button “save debug log” in my application to enable this behaviour at runtime.

Comment: You can use annotation based Aspects with AspectJ

Comment: What you're after is called aspect-oriented programming or short AOP. As Sven said AspectJ is one implementation you could use.